# Python: Button Command in Array

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, button, command

I'm trying to simplify the code of a calculator.

Instead of having code for each button, I am attempting to put it all in a for loop, but getting the buttons to actually have separate commands is proving to be difficult.

At the moment the code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

win = Tk()

counter = 0
button_text = ("M", "(", ")", "C", "7", "8", "9", "-", "4", "5", "6", "+", "1", "2", "3", "*", "AC", "0", ".", "=")
button_ids = []
label = Label(text="Enter text here", )
label.grid(row=10, column=1, columnspan=4)


def click(n):
    global label
    # get index and ID of button
    print(n)
    button_name = (button_ids[n])
    button_name.configure(text=f"clicked {button_ids[n]}")
    label.config(text=f"{button_ids[n]} clicked")


for r in range(5):
    for c in range(4):
        # create buttons & assign unique arg (i) to run function (change)
        button = Button(win, width=15, text=button_text[counter], command=partial(click, r))
        button.grid(row=r, column=c)
        # add ID to list
        button_ids.append(button)
        # update counter for next button text
        counter += 1

print(button_ids)

win.mainloop()
```

With just one for loop it works, but adding the second to create the array, doesn't.

How can I get each button to work/register properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `command=partial(click, counter)`, because function `click` need `button_ids[n]`.

And maybe change `button_ids` to `button_text`, if you need display button name.

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

win = Tk()

counter = 0
button_text = ("M", "(", ")", "C", "7", "8", "9", "-", "4", "5", "6", "+", "1", "2", "3", "*", "AC", "0", ".", "=")
button_ids = []
label = Label(text="Enter text here", )
label.grid(row=10, column=1, columnspan=4)


def click(n):
    global label
    # get index and ID of button
    print(n)
    button_name = (button_ids[n])
    # button_name.configure(text=f"clicked {button_ids[n]}")
    label.config(text=f"{button_text[n]} clicked")


for r in range(5):
    for c in range(4):
        print(counter, r, c)
        # create buttons & assign unique arg (i) to run function (change)
        button = Button(win, width=15, text=button_text[counter], command=partial(click, counter))
        button.grid(row=r, column=c)
        # add ID to list
        button_ids.append(button)
        # update counter for next button text
        counter += 1

print(button_ids)

win.mainloop()
```